# How Do I disable the button that hides/shows the toolbar in CKEdtor 3.0?

Tags: configuration, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm current creating a custom configuration for a CKEditor installation. I got all fixed, besides disabling the toggle button that hides/shows the toolbar.
So my question is: "How Do I disable the button that hides/shows the toolbar in CKEdtor 3.0?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CKEDITOR.config.toolbarCanCollapse`

at [CKEditor 3.0 JavaScript API Documentation CKEDITOR.config](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html)

Alternatively, locate that toggle button and script something to hide it or detach events from it.

Comment: Ok it's official I'm  blind. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @norbertB: We all are blinded occasionally, glad I can be of help :P